# Is there a Module Tree in Angular application?

Tags: angular

I know that there is an Injector Tree and a component tree in an Angular Application. But I have 3 questions:

1. Is there a Module Tree in an Angular application?
2. How to get a Module instance if it exists?
3. When I import my Shared Module into multi Feature Modules, do I get multi Shared Module instance, or just a singleton Shared Module instance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes there is a Module Tree, All modules travel to the root module `app.module.ts`
2. You can access a Module Instance by importing the module into another module: `import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';`
   and including it in your imports: `imports: [SharedModule]` 
   just make sure your module exports something, like: 
   `exports: [ListHighlightDirective,RedGreenDirective]`
   so you can access it in other modules.
3. You get multiple instances of the module if you import it into multiple other modules, otherwise you just get one.

Comment: Question 2. I know I can use ListHighlightDirective in templates of AnotherModule if I import SharedModule into AnotherModule. But I want to know how can I get the instance of SharedModule inside AnotherModule.